# How to reference the members of autogenerated columns in a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to get a reference to an GridView's autogenerated column.  The columns are autogenerated because the table datasource can be from one of multiple different tables in the backing SQL database; the fields are not known ahead of time.  My goal is to do type-checking against a stored list of intended types by field (or really, saved meta-information about each field) when the user updates.  I am getting stuck on how `DataBind()` does not actually create referrable objects in the `GridView.Columns` member, however, and I cannot see a way to get a reference to these columns.

The following code is as best I could manage, but of course fails on the line where I try to pull the HeaderText of the column.

```
Private Sub gvwResults_CommitEditOperation(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles gvwResults.RowUpdating
    Try
    Dim fields As List(Of UITableField) = CType(Session("TableFields"), List(Of UITableField))

    Dim row As GridViewRow = gvwResults.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
        'first check: confirm all types are correct

        'get cell column index so we can find the column so we can get the header text so we can match that against the UI fields
        'UI fields in turn have the appropriate type per field, so then parse the input text and see if they match
        Dim col As Integer = row.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell)
        If {0, 1}.Contains(col) Then Continue For   'ignore edit and delete columns
        
        'SO: This is the line where it fails
        Dim header As String = gvwResults.Columns(col).HeaderText
        Dim validType As Type = fields.First(Function(t) t.Name = header).DataType

        'SO: This is all untested, forgive me if you see obvious errors here, haven't gotten to it yet
        Dim value As Object
        If Double.TryParse(cell.Text, value) Then
            'tryparse assigns if parseable, no action necessary
        ElseIf Integer.TryParse(cell.Text, value) Then
            'see first if
        Else
            value = cell.Text   'default to string and pray for the best
        End If

        'value is at this point either the Type object for double, integer, or string as appropriate to the entered data
        'if that matches the indicated field from the Xml data, we're all peachy
        If Not Object.Equals(validType, value.GetType()) Then
            Throw New DataException($"Invalid data supplied to edited row in column {header}")
        End If
    Next
    Catch ex As DataException 'TODO: handle stuff
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Each cell *does* have a column index as though the column collection continued, but that index doesn't appear to be usable to actually access the column it's in anywhere.  I have already tried getting to it via `TableCell.Parent`, but that returns the GridViewRow, not a column.

Is there a way to get a reference to this column?  Or is this not possible and I will have to create a new page for every table?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is to deal with this at the data table level BEFORE you ever send to the gridview.

In other words, since the Gridview is really going to "eventually" output standard HTML that works in any browser, then you are best to put efforts into changing, manipulating , and dealing with the data source LONG before you ever feed such a source to the GridView.

So, we can assume this grid view - no columns, no much of anything.

Say this markup (with two buttons for 2 different tables). Thus:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdHotels" runat="server" Text="View Hotels"
            CssClas="btn" OnClick="cmdHotels_Click"
            />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdFighters" runat="server" Text="View Fighters"
            CssClas="btn" style="margin-left:35px"
            OnClick="cmdFighters_Click"
            />

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" >
        </asp:GridView>
```

and code behind:

```
Protected Sub cmdHotels_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    GridView1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active
            FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")

    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub

Protected Sub cmdFighters_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim rstData As DataTable =
        MyRst("SELECT FighterName, Fighter, Engine, Thrust, Description
            FROM Fighters")

    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

And now the result is this:

[image]

I mean, we can even do this. Let's drop in a third button.

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdFakeTable" runat="server" Text="View Fake Table"
            CssClas="btn" style="margin-left:35px"
            OnClick="cmdFakeTable_Click"
            />
```

This code:

```
Protected Sub cmdFakeTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    rstData.Columns.Add("First")
    rstData.Columns.Add("Last")
    rstData.Columns.Add("City")


    For i = 1 To 6
        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstData.NewRow
        OneRow("First") = $"First #{i}"
        OneRow("Last") = $"Last #{i}"
        OneRow("City") = $"City #{i}"

        rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow)
    Next

    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now we see this:

[image]

So, you are free to add columns, create any heading you want (by use of column name).

As you can see, it far easier to modify the data source.

Note that you can EVEN use expressions for the columns!

So, say for hotels, we want to combine the First Name + Last name into one column. You can do this:

```
    Dim rstData As DataTable =
        MyRst("Select FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active
            From tblHotelsA Order By HotelName")

    rstData.Columns.Add("FullName")
    rstData.Columns("FullName").Expression = "[FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]"

    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

And now we see this:

[image]

### Edit 2: Modify the GridView after loading

So, as above shows, you are FAR better off to modify the data source, even deleting columns, or adding them as you please.

But, you can modify values AFTER the fact, (but I really don't see the point or reason to do so).

So, for example, we can change the heading after the fact, and even change the text value after the fact.

So say like this:

```
    Dim rstData As DataTable =
        MyRst("Select FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description, Active
            From tblHotelsA Order By HotelName")

    rstData.Columns.Add("FullName")
    rstData.Columns("FullName").Expression = "[FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]"

    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()


    ' change column HotelName in grid view
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Text = "MyHotelName"

    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        gRow.Cells(3).Text = gRow.Cells(3).Text.ToUpper
    Next
```

And now we get/see this:

[image]

But, as noted, I think you are far better off to modify the data source and add (or remove) columns BEFORE you send such data to the gridview.

Comment: The data that I'm sending to the GridView from the database is already type-checked, it's the data that the user is inputting from the UI edit operation that I am struggling with.  When the user tries to edit the row, they can type in anything they want as a string, but some fields are not string types, so I have saved the names of the fields in the backing data and what type they are supposed to be and am trying to check the value for each cell in the updating row against that type.

Comment: Oh my! So the issue is not changing the headings (like my code shows). The issue is not changing the cell values (like my code shows). The issue not having different data sources (like my code shows).  But, the huge massive elephant in the room is we are trying to edit this data!  Ouch!!! Ok, vast and massive different problem, right? So, your looking to strong type the controls for editing then? Geesh, ok, so then getting values of cells (like my code shows) is not the issue.  I have to think about this, since I can't say I have a good edit solution here.

Comment: I think controls with textmode = number etc., and even a proper input mask is what you need, since this is a editing problem, not that of changing a cell value. Hum, I think a gridview might not be the solution here as a result of this fantastic new found information you shared.

Comment: Regardless of my suggesting, your Header test? each cell does NOT have a heading, only the heading row - see my 3rd example in which I AFTER binding the GV I change the header. So, the mistake in your code is to try and change header text on a given row, you  have to use GridView.headerRow as per my example code. So, you still are free to get/change/see the cells value for each column - but header text is separate row.